# make: *** No rule to make target `build_dev'. Stop

Tags: command-line

i am trying to install TCPDF by following [this github link](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf)

[image]

i downloaded zip code form git hub and place in this folder **/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6 - tcpdf** now i ran first 2 commands succesfully, when i tried 3rd command **make build_dev** i am getting error as in below image :

**No rule to make target `build_dev'. Stop.**

i am tried command from this path also : `/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6`

[image]

**update** i tried running commands with correct path where i copied the **extracted tcpdf folder**

[image]

Comment: You need to extract the .zip file and then run the command inside the project folder, where there is a Makefile. `make` can't find a 'build-dev' target, probably because there isn't a Makefile in the folder you are running the command on..

Comment: @IanC  thanks a lot, your comment mean `getting water in desert`, i updated question, please check `update` part in question....